# Is it good to to deploy Nginx, Nodejs and Redis together one virtual machine on GCP?

Tags: node.js, nginx, google-cloud-platform, redis

I'm developing my project, which use Nginx as proxy server, nodejs to deploy vuejs and socketio, Redis to store real-time data.
I just learned how to deploy project on GCP Computing Engine, and didn't learned how to use container, so my services will deploy on GCP Computing Engine's Virtual Machines for now.
To save my GCP free quota, I want to deploy Nginx, Nodejs and Redis on one virtual machine, and deploy my backend framework on another one.
Will this cause any problem?

Comment: There are no issues with deploying as many services/applications as you desire on a single VM provided that the VM has the resources to service your requirements. Keep in mind that a single VM becomes a single point of failure. Edit your question with details on what your requirements are for each service/application. In the same way you build a house, plan, write it down, review, update and then build.

Comment: Thank you, how about Redis? I know how it works, but could it consume a whole VM's resources?

Comment: Yes, a Redis instance can consume an entire VM. In fact some setups deploy multiple instances just for Redis. Part of designing a system is understanding how to configure and manage them.

Comment: Understood, Tank you very much!